# Class not registered errors with sharpDX

Tags: class, sharpdx

I'm trying some sharpDX examples and I;m getting this "Class not registered". I figure from the error its an os thing but I dont see why? I have installed the DX run-time as mentioned n the sharpDX page and I'm using windows7 64. This is a win32 app though.

error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll

Additional information: HRESULT: [0x80040154], Module: [SharpDX.DirectInput], ApiCode: [DIERR_DEVICENOTREG/DeviceNotRegistered], Message: Class not registered


stack
SharpDX.dll!SharpDX.Result.CheckError() + 0x42 bytes    
SharpDX.DirectInput.dll!SharpDX.DirectInput.DirectInput.CreateDevice(System.Guid arg0, out System.IntPtr arg1, SharpDX.ComObject arg2) + 0xee bytes 
    SharpDX.DirectInput.dll!SharpDX.DirectInput.Device.Device(SharpDX.DirectInput.DirectInput directInput, System.Guid deviceGuid) + 0x52 bytes 
    SharpDX.DirectInput.dll!SharpDX.DirectInput.CustomDevice<SharpDX.DirectInput.JoystickState,SharpDX.DirectInput.RawJoystickState,SharpDX.DirectInput.JoystickUpdate>.CustomDevice(SharpDX.DirectInput.DirectInput directInput, System.Guid deviceGuid) + 0x68 bytes  
    SharpDX.DirectInput.dll!SharpDX.DirectInput.Joystick.Joystick(SharpDX.DirectInput.DirectInput directInput, System.Guid deviceGuid) + 0x40 bytes
```

Code:
  joystickState = new JoystickState();
  Guid foundDevice = new Guid();
  joystick = new Joystick(directInput, foundDevice);

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are not using correctly the API. The Guid should match a registered DirectInput Joystick Guid. Check more carefully the sample [JoystickApp](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/WindowsDesktop/DirectInput/JoystickApp/Program.cs#L38) that is dealing exactly with this.